# How can I host a "replaceable" PDF file on google drive for my website?

Tags: html, pdf, google-drive-api

I am hosting a website and want to view **one pdf** file from there (which I have **uploaded on a public folder of Google Drive**). Now, I want my client to be able to **"replace"** that file, but still want my website to work with the **same link** I have had provided in the html **(don't want to edit the link every time she replaces the file)**.  Is that possible? Or any other similar alternatives?

**P.S : I am a beginner in web development.**

Comment: You want to update a PDF file on Google Drive without changing the file ID. If my understanding is correct, you can achieve it using [the files.update method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) of Drive API.

Comment: @Tanaike yes, your are right about not changing the id. But  I want my **client** to be able to replace the pdf file by accessing that google drive account. I want her to be able to do that through the google drive website, not the api.

Comment: But yes, am now considering your solution, that could be an alternative. But let me know if it is possible my way

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your case, for example, how about using Service Account? [Ref1](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts?hl=en), [Ref2](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts?hl=en)The Service Account can access to only the PDF file, and the clients can update the PDF file using the Service Account. If this was not what you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you very much. Yes, that is exactly what I want. I am looking that up.

Comment: As other workaround, you can also achieve it using [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). In this case, Web Apps is created by Google Apps Script, and this workaround can also update only the target file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192199/discussion-between-abu-obaida-and-tanaike).